# Include images with lower resolution

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, file-size

I need to include many JPG images in a LaTeX document. They are quite "heavy" (many MBs each), but in my document they will be printed in a very small size (~2x2 cm). Obviously

```
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{...}
```

actually lets me include them as expected but the resulting PDF file is too "heavy" (some GBs).

I know I could use an external image editor to decrease the file size but, for a couple of reasons too long to explain here, **I'd prefer to set the image resolution (so that a lower resolution implies a lower PDF file size) from within LaTeX**.

**Is there a reasonably simple way to achieve it?**

I'm using pdfLaTeX and the document I'm working on has no other peculiarities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{example.jpg}
% ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't find a tex solution, you could compress the images in the finished pdf: https://askubuntu.com/a/477798

Comment: @samcarter Well, thank you! If a TeX solution is not available, I'll do as you suggest.

Comment: I would suggest that if finished image scale is ~2 cm x ~2 cm the images size could well be only 118 x 118 pixels in colour I would thus avoid JPEG at such a small size artefacts are annoying, this is based on a median of 150 dpi better suited to Hi-Res PNG @ 10-15 kb each = about **70 images per Mb**, ideally vectors are best for users to zoom into but photos at 300 dpi are usually four times the overhead with only double the value  etc. 400 dpi + was considered criminal in terms of wasted user resources, though some super computer users will accept the decompression overheads.